# I have trouble replicating a design of a background in CSS

Tags: css, web

I have a design that I need to replicate with CSS.
[The background should be centered in the div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6hFF.png)

I tried using gradients, but they are not looking good on different browsers.

Comment: what if you show us your code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way with Flexbox :

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/jeremythille/pen/VQKYBY)

```css
section {
  border: #f00 solid 2px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  height: 400px;
}
section .aligner {
  border: #00f dashed 1px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  position: relative;
}
section .aligner .background {
  background: #ff0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%;
}
section .aligner .square {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #008000;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="aligner">
    <div class="background"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```